# How to make firebase push notifications work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have spent about 2 days going through firebases documentation, asking questions and looking at others and following youtube/medium tutorials and more. [Here is a github project with my full app delegate, so that all my code is visible.](https://github.com/makinggainz/notifications-project/tree/master)

But I am yet to figure out how to be able to send a notification message from firebase cloud messaging. I have setup Apple push services have gotten and inputed auth key into firebase and written code in my app delegate seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334926/why-are-notifications-sent-by-firebase-not-showing-up-on-my-phone)

**Can someone let me know what I need to do to make it work? What have I missed?**

Here is my `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")

}
```

### Update:

[I have followed again this whole documentation by firebase and still sending notifications from fire cloud messaging does not work.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Clearly however the code is running given that 2 lines I have which save the token to firebase successfully save the token.

Comment: did you implement `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`? Could you provide this piece of code?

Comment: check update...

Comment: don't forget to check production/development mode

Comment: Where do I find this? @Vyacheslav

Comment: check certificates and admin panel of firebase

Comment: I cannot find what you mean I think you mean service accounts but there there is nothing of production /dev @Vyacheslav

Comment: Have you check for the certificates in the apple developer console. Are you on a paid developer membership?

Comment: Yes I am a business one, @AakashDave. I have two certificates, Apple push and the normal

Comment: Great so there are technically 3 certs. [1. Development Cert, 2. Production Cert, 3. APNS Auth Key ]. You have them all?

Comment: @AakashDave under all it says 2 certificates, but under keys I . have the APNs auth key

Comment: And if you have plugged in everything perfectly that should be good. What is the issue you are facing and what is the error if any exactly

Comment: I am not getting any error, the issue is that in the firebase cloud messaging console when I make and send a notif it does not show up on my device. @AakashDave

Comment: Have you printed out a result for each step through your nodejs code to be certain everything is going through?

Comment: I'm asking this to figure out if this is a problem with your cloud function setup or your device setup. Ensuring the console spits out a log at the end of the function would say this is definitely an issue on the device end. Plus, not all cloud function issues will show up as an error.

Comment: Although I do have a nodejs backend which I intend to be able to handel notifications, up to this point all I am trying to accomplish is to be able to send a notification via firebase cloud messaging console. @AdrianMurray

Comment: Ah, so definitely a problem on your device end. Are you at least getting a request to receive notifications on the device?

Comment: When first downloading the app (deleting and running again), yes. @AdrianMurray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194082/discussion-between-adrian-murray-and-nct-127).

Comment: In fact, do you have the right checks in capabilities?? Push Notifications on, background mode and remote notifications? Also, do you have your last version of GoogleService-Info.plist? Can you check of the file is in the right place.

Comment: @m1sh0 yes to all the things you mentioned. Except: do I have to download a new google.plist after installing cloud messaging?

Comment: What do you mean installing cloud messaging, like in pods? I think you need it if you change configurations in the firebase console. You don't lose anything if you replace it with the last one from the console. And as far as I understand you have everything else. I don't remember if you had apns key or certificates(please set up your apns key I think it is better).

Comment: @m1sh0 I re-downloaded it and still it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a problem like this in the past, what fixed it for me was checking the `bundle ID` is the same on both the auth key and fire project as well as in Xcode.

Also to make sure your app delegate code is correct just use [Firebase's example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/README.md):

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the APNS Auth Key correctly configured in the firebase console, and considering your appDelegate implementation you have provided, the only piece of code i see missing is the **FIRInstanceId** creation.

According to Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/InstanceID) :

> Instance ID provides a unique identifier for each app instance and a mechanism >to authenticate and authorize actions (for example, sending an FCM message).
>
> Once an InstanceID is generated, the library periodically sends information >about the application and the device where it’s running to the Firebase >backend.

And [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/Messaging)

> To send or receive messages, the app must get a registration token from >FIRInstanceID. This token authorizes an app server to send messages to an app >instance.

Just before where you register for remote notification in your *application didFinishLaunching...*, add this before the  **application.registerForRemoteNotifications()**

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
    } else if let result = result {
        print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps :)